# Oracle delete skip locked

Tags: oracle, sql-delete, dml

Does oracle allows to delete rows from a table with some condition and skip the locked once

```
DELETE from t 
 WHERE t.id IN (SELECT id 
                  FROM t 
                 WHERE id in ('1','2') 
                   FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED )
```

For example id 2 is locked by other session and deletion script should skip that row

The query above always ***fails with error***

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Version :  Oracle 11G XE

Comment: The subquery looks superfluous - what happens if you try `DELETE from t WHERE t.id IN ('1','2') FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp it has a syntax issue, sorry for late reply didn't had access to machine for last couple of days

Comment: try kfinity's answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on Jeffrey's answer, I believe this clause was intended for use in PL/SQL blocks. So you could try this, for example:

```
begin
  for r in (select rowid as rid from t for update skip locked)
  loop
    delete from t where rowid = r.rid;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

The `FOR UPDATE` clause is only valid for the top-level SQL statement, not for subqueries.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55370